# Dijkstra Counter Example

Tags: algorithms

I an brushing up on Dijkstra (specifically Wikipedia's pseudocode) and can't resolve this counter example. I want the shortest path between A and E. I would move from A to C to D, where D would have a cost of 105. Once I mark D as visited I no longer have an opportunity to find the correct path A to B to D to E. What am I missing?

[image: Is this a counter Example]

Answer (score 4):

initially you have:
Q={A, B, C, D, E}
dist(A)=0, dist(B)=dist(C)=dist(D)=dist(E)=inf
previous(A)=previous(B)=previous(C)=previous(D)=previous(E)=undefined

from Q the vertex with min distance is A. Therefore you choose A and you do
(dist(A)+length(A,B)

your remove A from Q, now you have
Q={B, C, D, E}
In Q the vertex with the min dist is C with dist(C)=5, so you pick C
the only vertex adjacent to C is D so you have
(dist(C)+length(C,D)

you remove C from Q, now you have
Q={B, D, E}
the vertex with the min dist in Q is B so you pick B
(dist(B)+length(B,D)

you remove B from Q, now you have
Q={D, E}
the vertex with the min dist in Q is D so you pick D
(dist(D)+length(D, E)

you remove D from Q, now you have
Q={E}
the vertex with the min dist in Q is E so you pick E
No neighboors
remove E from Q
Q is empty and the algorithm terminates
previous(E)=D
previous(D)=B
previous(B)=A
so this is your shortest path from A to E

I skipped the distance checking for the previous vertex for simplicity (it is always equal), the algorithm performs this check. I think you confuse picking a vertex from the set Q and changing the distance of a vertex. They are two different things. The fact that you are assigning a distance at some point to a vertex does not mean that it will be final. It will be final only when this vertex have the minimum distance in the set Q and it will be the one to be picked next and removed. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Yes that was clear... thank you. I wasn't picking the node with the min distance. Instead I was picking the neighbor with the min distance.

Answer (score 1):

D would not yet have become the current node. A node can only be marked as visited if all of its connections have been explored, to explore it must be the current node selected. To be selected it must have the lowest weight assigned to it, B would have already been visited and d's value updated to reflect that since b has a value of 10 and D is a value of 105, Its a priority queue, not a regular queue that you use.